# Dimension of vector space in P3

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I need help on the following question. I have no idea how to attempt it.

Find the dimension of the vector space:
$$
 {p(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d \in P_3:p'(1) = 0}.
$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align} p'(x) &= 3ax^2 + 2bx + c  \\
p'(1) &= 0 \iff 3a + 2b + c = 0 \iff c = -(3a + 2b)
\end{align}

This means that you lose a degree of freedom, and subspace contains polynomials of the form
$$p(x) = ax^3 +bx^2 - (3a+2b)x + d.$$

Can you figure out the dimension from this?

Comment: Yes! the dimension would be 3 then? Since losing 1 degree of freedom implies that the dimension reduces by 1.

Comment: @Potato Indeed! You can describe any such polynomial with $3$ numbers, and $2$ numbers aren't enough, so the dimension is $3$.

Answer (score 1):

The dimension of Pn(F) is n+1 so for your P3, the dim=4.

Comment: That is correct, but the additional restriction of p'(1) = 0 somehow changes the dimension.